# "Then" is not working to fetch data from async and await

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, dio

I have an async class that fetch token from Flutter Secure Storage

```
  readSecureData(String key) async {
    String? data = await storage.read(key: key);
    print('data from secure storage: $data');
    return data;
  }
```

and I fetch the token with then method and store it in a variable token through a dio factory class as follows

```
class DioFactory {
  //not to have instance
  // ApiService._();
  final FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

          static Dio? dio;
    
      Dio getDio() {
        if (dio == null) {
          String? token = "";

     SecureStorage()
          .readSecureData("login_token")
          .then((value) => token = value);

      print("----------------dio");
      print(token);
      print("----------------dio");

      var headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer ${token ?? ''}"
      };

      BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: ApiConst.apiBaseUrl,
        headers: headers,
      );

      dio = Dio(options);
      return dio!;
    } else {
      return dio!;
    }
  }
```

but the token is always returned empty although there is a token and I can see the token is printed in readSecureData function, so how can i fetch the token from readSecureData and store it in the token to send it it the dio header

Comment: replace `then((value) => token = value)` with `then((value) {print('then: $value'); token = value;})` and you will see that `then` is working fine

Comment: Your code that prints token executes *before* the .then has had a chance to complete.  You need to await the result of your call to readSecureData, and use the result, not use a .then.

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately your method is not working :(

Comment: doesn't `print('then: $value')` show the right value?

Comment: the print shows the right value but the token returns empty because as @RandalSchwartz says the token executes before the .then to complete

Comment: that's why you should do your job in the callback passed to `then` method

Comment: but how to store token in a variable? when I do the following method SecureStorage().readSecureData("login_token").then((value) {
        token = value;
      }); it returns null

Comment: `SecureStorage().readSecureData("login_token").then((value) {final token = value; ... the rest of your code goes here })`

Comment: Or, just use await, as one of the answers already shows.

Comment: @pskink when i use Future<Dio> getDio() async {} it shows the following error - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'. - 'Dio' is from 'package:dio/src/dio.dart' ('/Users/shadyhesham/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dio-5.4.0/lib/src/dio.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'. Response response = await DioFactory().getDio().get(

Comment: It should be like this: `(await DioFactory().getDio()).get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  void anyFunction() {
    String? anyValue;
    Future.delayed(Durations.long1, () {
      return 'anyString';
    }).then((value) {
      anyValue = value;
    });

    print(anyValue);
  }
```

Look, here is a function that contains an async operation but is not defined as Future.

The output of this function is as follows:

```
flutter: null
```

Because the assignment process takes place without waiting for the Future.delay process.

---

This is a function defined as Future and it does the same job.

```
  Future<void> anyFunction() async {
    String? anyValue;
    await Future.delayed(Durations.long1, () {
      return 'anyString';
    }).then((value) {
      anyValue = value;
    });

    print(anyValue);
  }
```

And here this output:

```
flutter: anyString
```

Did you understand ?

You have use this way :

```
 Future<Dio> getDio() async{
        if (dio == null) {
          String? token = "";

   await  SecureStorage()
          .readSecureData("login_token")
          .then((value) => token = value);

      print("----------------dio");
      print(token);
      print("----------------dio");

      var headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer ${token ?? ''}"
      };

      BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: ApiConst.apiBaseUrl,
        headers: headers,
      );

      dio = Dio(options);
      return dio!;
    } else {
      return dio!;
    }
```

Comment: when i use   Future<Dio> getDio() async {} it shows the following error - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Dio' is from 'package:dio/src/dio.dart' ('/Users/shadyhesham/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dio-5.4.0/lib/src/dio.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'.
    Response response = await DioFactory().getDio().get(

Comment: Share with us your complete code your getting error

Answer (score 0):

**`Future<String>:`** This `function` returns a **Future** that resolves to a **String**. This indicates that the operation is asynchronous, and when the data is ready, it will be a **string**.

**`async:`** This keyword is used to mark the `function` as asynchronous, allowing the use of `await` inside the `function`.

So, first, add `Future<String>` before `readSecureData()` method.

```
  Fture<String> readSecureData(String key) async {
    String? data = await storage.read(key: key);
    print('data from secure storage: $data');
    return "asdasd";
  }
```

And then get data from `readSecureData()`  using the following snippets.

```
String token = await SecureStorage()
          .readSecureData("login_token");
```

Comment: the problem is that Dio getDio() {} does not accept async and await and it shows the following error Functions marked 'async' must have a return type which is a supertype of 'Future'.
Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.